# Idioms and common English phrases related to music?

Tags: phrases, idiom-requests, music

I am writing a dissertation on musical education in developing countries.

I would like to find titles for my section that are catchy.

Does anyone have any recommendations for resources of music-related idioms or English phrases I could use?

I am not thinking about musical vocabulary, e.g. tenor, staccato, adagio, clarinet.

I am rather referring to phrases like "tin ear", "dance to the beat of your own drum", "blow your own horn", "fit as a fiddle", etc.

Comment: *This question is music to my ears*. Or maybe not - that one doesn't work very well in a text-based medium. Actually, I'm afraid it's an Off Topic "list" type question.

Comment: @FumbleFingers It's rather a "request for recommendations" question, and all that jazz...

Comment: Sadly, that's also Off Topic ([request for resources](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/2573/what-good-reference-works-on-english-are-available-online))

Comment: You absolutely *must* use "Difficult second album" somewhere, and "Contractual Obligation" :)

Comment: Based on the subject of your dissertation I’m guessing that your goal is to begin (or continue) your career as a music Teacher. Anyway, I hope that this is the case because your question indicates to me that your lucky Students have/would have a dynamic Teacher with creative ideas!  Unfortunately, being “close enough for jazz” doesn’t seem to be quite close enough here to avoid running afoul of the criteria for acceptable questions. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Try searching online for **music idioms**

I did and the second thing that came up was this

[Learn English Today](http://www.learn-english-today.com/idioms/idiom-categories/music/music.html)

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking to **Music has charms to soothe a savage breast**

what means:

> Music has the power to enchant even the roughest of people. This
>   proverb comes from the play The Mourning Bride, by William Congreve,
>   an English author of the late seventeenth and early eighteenth
>   centuries.

*from The American Heritage® New Dictionary of Cultural Literacy.*

Also the simple idiom : "**music soothes the soul**"